# Date Conversion in Hive from different Formats

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Customer table in Hive(custid bigint,custname string ,DOB string). The DOB has values in differnt formats(6/17/1969, 08/22/54, Jan 11 2003).
I have a requirement to convert the dates in the different format to a standardized date format (MM/dd/yy) and store it in another table in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

**1st -

 the ANSI/ISO standard is YYYY-MM-DD**

> When dates are represented with numbers they can be interpreted in
>   different ways. For example, 01/05/12 could mean January 5, 2012, or
>   May 1, 2012. On an individual level this uncertainty can be very
>   frustrating, in a business context it can be very expensive.
>   Organizing meetings and deliveries, writing contracts and buying
>   airplane tickets can be very difficult when the date is unclear.
>
> ISO 8601 tackles this uncertainty by setting out an internationally
>   agreed way to represent dates:
>
> YYYY-MM-DD
>
> For example, September 27, 2012 is represented as 2012-09-27.
>
> https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

**2nd -

If for some reason you're on an old hive version and you have to use string to hold your dates,  I would strongly recommend to avoid any other date format, for 2 reasons:**
1. This is the only format supported by the date functions.
2. This format allows correct alphabetical comparison, e.g. -
'2017-01-22' > '2016-09-22' but '01-22-2017' < '09-22-2016'